# adding listview hides form background image Xamarin ios

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working on Xamarin cross platform app.
I have have form where I am using form's `BackgroundImage = "timelinebackground.png";` on constructor to set background image.

Its working on fine Android but when I check same in iOS it's not showing background image.
When I remove listview from xaml then its background image is showing in iOS as well.

here is xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="BMTHomesApp.Views.Timeline">
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Text="Logout" Order="Primary" Priority="0" Clicked="MenuItem_OnClicked"></ToolbarItem>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <StackLayout>
        <ListView
    x:Name="timelineListView"
            ItemTapped="timelineListView_ItemTapped"
    ItemsSource="{Binding .}"
    RowHeight="75"
    SeparatorVisibility="None">


        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid ColumnSpacing="0" RowSpacing="0">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="25" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="{Binding ActualStartDate}" TextColor="#0073ae" />

                        <Label Grid.Column="2" Margin="20,0" FontSize="Medium" Text="{Binding StageName}" TextColor="#ffffff"/>

                        <!--<Label
              Grid.Row="1"
              Grid.Column="2"
              Margin="20,0"
              FontSize="Small"
              Text="Please add some desc text in api" TextColor="#ffffff"/>-->

                        <BoxView
                            Grid.RowSpan="2"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            BackgroundColor="#ffffff"
                            HorizontalOptions="Center"
                            VerticalOptions="Fill"
                            WidthRequest="1" />

                        <Image Grid.Column="1" Source="Bullet.png" HeightRequest="25" WidthRequest="25" />
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>

        <DatePicker x:Name="DatePickerTimeline" IsVisible="False"></DatePicker>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

and code behind:

```
public partial class Timeline : ContentPage
    {
        public Timeline ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
            NavigationPage.SetBackButtonTitle(this, "");
            Title = "TIMELINE";
            BackgroundImage = "timelinebackground.png";


            var constructionStages = GetConstructionStages();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(constructionStages.Result.Error))
            {
                DisplayAlert("Error", constructionStages.Result.Error, "Ok");
            }
            else
            {
                timelineListView.ItemsSource = constructionStages.Result.ConstructionStages;
            }

        }

        private void timelineListView_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
        {
            var selectedItem = (ConstructionStages) e.Item;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedItem.ActualStartDate))
            {
                DateTime dateTimeStart;
                if (DateTime.TryParse(selectedItem.ActualStartDate, out dateTimeStart))
                {
                    DatePickerTimeline.MinimumDate = dateTimeStart;
                }
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedItem.ActualCompletionDate))
            {
                DateTime dateTimeEnd;
                if (DateTime.TryParse(selectedItem.ActualCompletionDate, out dateTimeEnd))
                {
                    DatePickerTimeline.MaximumDate = dateTimeEnd;
                }
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedItem.ActualStartDate) ||
                !string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedItem.ActualCompletionDate))
            {
                DatePickerTimeline.Format = "MM-dd-yyyy";
                DatePickerTimeline.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#ffffff");
                //DatePickerTimeline.IsVisible = true;
                DatePickerTimeline.Focus();
            }
            else
            {
                timelineListView.SelectedItem = null;
            }
        }

        private async Task<ConstructionStagesResponse> GetConstructionStages()
        {
            ConstructionStageManager manager = new ConstructionStageManager();
            var result = await manager.GetConstructionStages(Application.Current.Properties["SessionId"].ToString());
            return result;
        }

        private async void MenuItem_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HelperClasses.LogOut();
            Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Login());
            //Navigation.PushAsync(new Login());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set your `ListView`'s `BackgroundColor` property to transparent for the Page's background image to be shown:

```
<ListView BackgroundColor="Transparent">
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I had tried all other things like removing each control one by one and spent hours that why its not working for iOS , as same is working for Android .

Comment: @Mahajan344 iOS `UIView`s have different background defaults then Android 's `View`s and Forms' does not override the defaults unless you tell it. Glad I could help 